# GNU Linker Resources

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, gnu

I want to know if there is some resource available, some book or something where I can learn about the code of GNU Linker. I have downloaded the code, but as I am new to this field was not able to make much out of it. I know what linkers do and all, but wanted to learn that how it is actually implemented. Some suggestions are also welcome, so as to how to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ian Lance Taylor did a long series of blog posts about linkers

- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/38
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/39
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/40
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/41
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/42
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/43
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/44
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/45
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/46
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/47
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/48
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/49
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/50
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/51
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/52
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/53
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/54
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/55
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/56
- http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/57

Maybe it would be worth starting with this paper introducing the new  Gold linker:

- http://research.google.com/pubs/pub34417.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.. blog entries are great :)..